# FIrestore DocumentSnapShot.exists always return false

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm Using `DocumentSnapshot.exists` to check if the doc exists or not but it returns false even if the doc is already exists

```
child: ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    DocumentSnapshot ds =
        await (DatabaseService().reportsCollection.doc(
              '${selectedTechnical.id} ${(DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(DateTime.now()).toString())}',
            )).get();
    if (ds.exists) {
      print("${ds.id} already exist");
    } else {
      DatabaseService().createNewReport(selectedTechnical);
      print("${ds.id} added");
    }
  },
........
```

this is print `"id added"` every time I press the button
how can I fix it??

Comment: We can't see the final string that becomes the name of the document, nor can we see the contents of your database, so there's nothing we can do tell if you might be doing something wrong.

Comment: I believe ds for every hit becomes something new in the database as you are passing the current time as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your code a bit:

```
 DocumentSnapshot ds =
                            await (DatabaseService().reportsCollection.doc(
                                  '${selectedTechnical.id} ${(DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(DateTime.now()).toString())}',
                                )).get().then((value) {

     if (value.exists) {
                          print("${value.id} already exist");
                        } else {
                          DatabaseService().createNewReport(selectedTechnical);
                          print("${value.id} added");
                        }
});
```

This way you know for sure that you get the value then check